# How to get all(!) closest directives/components in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Looking at :

```
<div class="widget-content">
  <div class="widget-content">
    <div>
        <widget-item></widget-item>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to get the *first(!) closest* `widget-content` within the `<widget-item></widget-item>` component.

It's pretty easy to do it by creating a directive  :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.widget-content'
})
export class WidgetContentDirective {
}
```

And by Injecting  to the constructor of `widget-item` :

```
constructor(private widgetContentQuery: WidgetContentDirective) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.widgetContentQuery);
  }
```

Result :

[image]

**Question:**

There are *two*  `widget-content` wrappers.
How can I get an `array` of them both  within the `widget-item` constructor ?

*full disclosure:*
for learning purpose. There is no real scenario. ( I'm not after jQuery solutions)

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tehhjv?file=app%2Fwidget-item%2Fwidget-item.component.ts)

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList but not sure it's what you are looking for

Comment: @Whisher That's not realted. View Children supplies you elements inside(!) the component. And you cn get them as query list or to `read` them differrently as native elements. that's not eh case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's an unusual request, but I believe there is a way to do this. It's not easy, but it uses an `InjectionToken` on the `WidgetContentDirective`:

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsqjjv)

Basically you've got this `InjectionToken`:

```
export const WidgetContents: InjectionToken<WidgetContentDirective[]> = 
  new InjectionToken('WIDGET_CONTENTS');
```

And using `@Optional()` and `@SkipSelf()` inject this in the providers array of your `WidgetContentDirective`, together with the current `WidgetContentDirective`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.widget-content',
  providers: [{
        provide: WidgetContents,
        useFactory: (
          widgetContent: WidgetContentDirective, 
          parents?: WidgetContentDirective[]
        ) => {
          // filter because of optional
          return [widgetContent, ...parents].filter(widget => widget);
        },
        deps: [
          forwardRef(() => WidgetContentDirective), 
          [new Optional(), new SkipSelf(), new Inject(WidgetContents)]
        ]
    }
  ]
})
```

You can then use this `InjectionToken` inside your `WidgetItemComponent`:

```
export class WidgetItemComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(WidgetContents)
    private widgetContentQuery: WidgetContentDirective[]
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.widgetContentQuery);
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is the part that it matches the parents ?

Comment: What do you mean with that? You are wondering how it gets the reference to a parent? This is done with the 2nd `deps`. There it says `SkipSelf`, which means it's going to look in it owns parents looking for `WidgetContents` and ignoring itself. This will return what it has in the `useFactory` of the parent. The `forwardRef` is a reference to itself. It's kinda difficult to explain, but you are right that this is a good learning example

Comment: Truly advanced approach. I should dig more to it. Thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir You're welcome. Took me a while to get to this as well. I first tried to use a `multi` provider and just return the reference of the current `WidgetContentDirective`, but that hit a dead end...somehow

Comment: @RoyiNamir FYI, the items in the array inside the `WidgetItemComponent` are from bottom to top. So the first parent is first and then the grandparent and so on